# Editing Wiki Page Issue

Tags: publishing-site, publishing, access-denied, wiki-pages

I believe I have found an odd issue with SP13 wiki pages - and I cannot seem to figure it out.  I have a wiki page that has web parts on the page.  One web part is connected to another document library.  The web parts are outside of the area that appears when a wiki page is created.

The issue is when a user with owner permissions edits, saves, and publishes a wiki page. When the user returns to the wiki page to make more edits a "you do not have access to this page" appears.  However, SharePoint shows that the user has the page "checked-out". The only way the user is able to successfully make edits to the wiki page - someone with admin rights has to force check the page back in.  Then the user can make edits again.

Has anyone ever experienced this issue?

NOTE: The site has Publishing features turned-on.